# Differentiability of $f(x,y)= e^{-\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f(x,y)= e^{-\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}}$ when $(x,y)\ne(0,0)$

```
       = 0 when  (x,y)=(0,0)
```

Then f(x,y) is

(a) not continuous at (0,0)

(b) continuous at (0,0) but doesn't have first order partial order derivative

(C) continuous at (0,0) and has first order partial order derivative, but not differentiable at (0,0)

(d) differentiable at (0,0)

I could check that the function is continuous at (0,0) but I am stuck at partial derivatives and differentiability

Comment: For partial derivatives, you need to decide whether $\lim_{x\to0}e^{-1/x^2}/x$ exists.

Comment: Yes, the limit exists and is equal to 0, so partial derivatives exist

Answer (score 2):

For partial derivatives we have

$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{e^{-\frac1{h^2}}}{h} =0$$

and for differentiability check by definition

$$\lim_{(h,k)\to (0,0)} \frac{e^{-\frac1{h^2+k^2}}}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}} =0$$

or as an alternative that partial derivatives are continuous at $(0,0)$.